# Изменение стиля конкретного блока при определенном выбранном radio button

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, html5, вёрстка

Необходимо, чтобы при выборе определенного radio-button менялось свойство соответствующего блока. на чистом js. 
Укажите пожалуйста ошибку или более рациональный вариант.

```js
function Selected() {

  if (document.getElementById("package1").checked === true) {
    document.getElementById("box1").style.display = "block";
    console.log("BUBA");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("box1").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="package1" class="header__package-label">
      <input type="radio" id="package1" name="packages" oninput="Selected" 
      value="pack1" checked><i></i>p1
    </label>
<label for="package2" class="header__package-label">
      <input type="radio" id="package2" name="packages" oninput="Selected" 
      value="pack2"><i></i>p2
    </label>
<label for="package3" class="header__package-label">
      <input type="radio" id="package3" name="packages" oninput="Selected" 
      value="pack3"><i></i>p3
    </label>
<div class="header__package-on-box" id="box1">
  <p>1</p>
</div>
<div class="header__package-on-box" id="box2">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="header__package-on-box" id="box3">
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Консоль не ругается и ошибок не выдает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще если говорить откровенно там все надо менять, Но в конкретном случае

> onchange="Selected()"

в место

> oninput="Selected"

В итоге ты не то событие выбрал и забыл про скобки чтобы запустить функцию

```js
//Что бы не писать для каждого варианта громосткие условия 
// лучше использовать циклы

const input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('header__package-on-box');

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      // И желательно не со стилями играть, а добавлять и удалять классы
      // со стилями то не беда, а вот если использовать 
      // display = "none" и display = "block"
      // то теряем возможность плавно менять что-то 
      // так как  transition-У display = "none" не подвластен
      box[i].classList.remove('box')
    }
    box[i].classList.add('box')
  })
}
```

```css
.header__package-on-box {
  opacity: 0;
  background: orange;
  transition: background .5s .3s, opacity .5s;
}

.box {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: background .5s, opacity .5 .3s;
}
```

```html
<label for="package1" class="header__package-label">
      <input type="radio" id="package1" name="packages"
      value="pack1" checked><i></i>p1
    </label>
<label for="package2" class="header__package-label">
      <input type="radio" id="package2" name="packages" 
      value="pack2"><i></i>p2
    </label>
<label for="package3" class="header__package-label">
      <input type="radio" id="package3" name="packages" 
      value="pack3"><i></i>p3
    </label>
<div class="header__package-on-box box" id="box1">
  <p>1</p>
</div>
<div class="header__package-on-box" id="box2">
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div class="header__package-on-box" id="box3">
  <p>3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Заработало. Подскажи пожалуйста, а как лучше реализовать эту задачу?

Comment: Щас переделаю....

Comment: Кстати, вариантов куча...  Может кто еще, чего-то посоветует...